# How can I highlight the vanishing-partials in an interactive 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I am using `Manipulate` and `Plot3D` to plot a function with two real variables and two extra parameters.

```
f[x_, y_, alpha_, gamma_] := x*y + alpha*x - Log[Power[x, gamma]*y]   
Manipulate[
    Plot3D[f[x, y, alpha, gamma], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4]],
    {alpha, -100, 100, 0.1}, {gamma, -100, 
    100, 0.1}]
```

I want to dynamically highlight/plot the 3D curve (or set of points) of the vanishing partials (`D[f, x] == D[f, y] == 0`) over the function, and have it update according to the parameter values manipulated.

I know I should probably use `NDSolve` for this, But I need the solution to be updated and displayed on parameter changes. How do I do that?

Comment: maybe, related blog post: http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/01/08/volumetric-rendering-of-colliding-galaxies/

Answer (score 4):

I would use `MeshFunctions`, although self-intersecting mesh lines usually aren't connected properly.  Increasing `PlotPoints` helps.

```
g[x_, y_] := Cos[2 x + y] + y^3/2 - y;
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotPoints -> ControlActive[Automatic, 50], MeshStyle -> {Blue, Red},
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Derivative[1, 0][g][x, y]], 
   Function[{x, y, z}, Derivative[0, 1][g][x, y]]}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}, {0}}]
```

[image: Output of plot]

I had already written the example, before your edit adding your code appeared.  Here is the principle applied to your code:

```
f[x_, y_, alpha_, gamma_] := x*y + alpha*x - Log[Power[x, gamma]*y]
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[f[x, y, alpha, gamma], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.4], 
  PlotPoints -> ControlActive[Automatic, 50], 
  MeshStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Derivative[1, 0, 0, 0][f][x, y, alpha, gamma]], 
    Function[{x, y, z}, Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][f][x, y, alpha, gamma]]}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}, {0}}],
 {alpha, -100, 100, 0.1}, {gamma, -100, 100, 0.1}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael E2 ! And another thing.. How do I keep the same functionality but have `alpha` and `gamma` not be arguments of `f`?

Comment: You could put the function definition inside `Manipulate` and set `TrackedSymbols :> {alpha, gamma}`.